# Quickbooks POS AddOn Sales Reciept TxnID

Tags: add-on, quickbooks

I am creating my first AddOn using Quickbooks POS AddOn Dev Kit v10.

I have created a button in the receipts side buttons panel. 
Now what I want is the current sales receipt.

For that, what I am trying to do is to get TxnID and query request processor, with that TxnID to get the whole receipt.

I have managed to get information like Qty, Desc1, ItemNum etc. I have also get the  Receipt Schema.

https://idnforums.intuit.com/messageview.aspx?catid=49&threadid=16722
From above url, it says DocSID is the TxnID, but I cant get the field value through DocSID.

How can I get the TxnID or is there a better way to do it for getting the current sales reciept?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working on it for 2-3 days, I came to know that TxnID will be created after the sales receipt is saved in QB POS through the IPOSService ProcessQBPOSXMLRequest method.

ProcessQBPOSXMLRequest only takes and repond in XML format. I created the receipt request in XML and send it ProcessQBPOSXMLRequest for processing.

I was avoding creatingg the XML request, since it was a long and tedious work, but I did similar work while creating another application with QBPOS SDK v3, with QBPOSFC3 library. I copied the code and add reference to QBPOSFC3.dll, and created xml from IMsgSetRequest interface which send request to POS request processor and convert the request in XML format.